# PDF Low Level - Writing text in absolute location

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation

I'm writing a PDF file directly from code.

I'm now at the stage where I'm writing text onto the page, and have all the words and coordinates, but I can't get it to put them in exactly the right place. Acrobat thinks that each word should be on a new line and it ends up looking like this:

```
word
     word
          word
               word
```

Instead of:

```
word word word word
```

This is what I'm using:

```
q
Tr 3
 BT
  /F1 8 Tf
  10 1000 Td
  (word)Tj
 ET
 BT
  /F1 8 Tf
  50 1000 Td
  (word)Tj
 ET
Q
```

I know that `Td` is likely wrong, but I can't find what the correct command is to do this. I have the PDF specification open, but it's not very clear - doesn't explain how to position each word absolutely.

Comment: I can't give you an answer because I have only just started looking at generating PDFs myself, but using exactly the same codes as you the text my program is outputting goes exactly where I expect it to. Is it possible there is some code elsewhere that is causing the repositioning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code seems to work

```
q 
  0 Tr 
  /Helv 12 Tf 
  BT 
    1 0 0 1 10 10 Tm 
    (Hello)Tj
  ET
  BT 
    1 0 0 1 90 10 Tm 
   (World)Tj
  ET
Q
```

'1 0 0 1 10 10 Tm' sets the text matrix with a scaling of 1,1 and x,y at 10, 10.

There are ways to combine text strings into a string of commands to make it more efficient.